# How to run php in an HTML file running python?

Tags: php, python, include

I get an "unhandled exception" every time I try to run this standard include in an html file running python:

```
<?php
//add header with tabs
include('includes/templates/common/tpl_header.php');
?>
```

I'm trying to run it right under the body tag that looks like this:

```
<body py:match="body" py:attrs="h.append_class_attr(attrs, 'mcore-body')" py:with="
    attrs = h.attrs_to_dict(select('@*'));
    body_class = attrs.get('class', '').split(' ');
    advertising_banner_html = g.settings['advertising_banner_html'];
">
```

... sorry but I'm not the most avid programmer, how do you get that puppy to run?!

Comment: Please explain better. Which file is what? Which one is running Python?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel my first reaction exactly!

Comment: ok, I'm obviously in over my head... BUT, I figure I might as well try to figure this out. To answer your question, I have an html file running python, I want to run php inside this file so I can pull in part of my template files... is it even possible? Isn't there something similar to php includes for python?

Comment: Sorry but the quality of this question far beyond of one would call a reasonable question.

Comment: @RestRisiko, at least there's an error message and code. This isn't a bad question; it's just missing context...

Comment: @Gautama Swamy: so your server is actually a python daemon, and you want to know how to execute PHP scripts on this make-shift http server? Same as the question posted on the front page a few above this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591230/php-webserver-in-python)?

Comment: @Gautama Swamy: Context for your question is missing entirely, so no answer can be guaranteed.  Perhaps you could add additional tags to your question related to any techniques or frameworks you're using, such as "Genshi" as mentioned by abhinavg.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is HTML, Python is Python and PHP is PHP.
It's THREE different technologies, which **cannot be mixed.**
You **can't** "run standard PHP include" in HTML file.
You **can't** "run standard PHP include" in Python file.
You can run PHP code in PHP file only.

You can't run Python code in HTML file. You can run Python code in Python file only.

So, whole question makes no sense.

It seems you should forget PHP while working with Python and use Python features for including files. Of course it shouldn't be PHP file, but Python or at least HTML file

Comment: Actualy you can run standard PHP include in HTML file!

Comment: For example on Apache server you can add next lines to .htaccess: RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
and after it all HTML files will be parse via PHP, so code like <? include_once('some_file.php');?> will do the same sing like in php file.

Comment: @ARTstudio you're making PHP file out of HTML this way. We are talking not of changing extensions tricks.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: giving ARTstudio benefit of the doubt, technically that is correct if PHP is the interpreter of that file.  By `including` a file type of any kind (image, zip, etc), all embedded and clear PHP code/text within will be executed as PHP, just like any other PHP script file.

Comment: thank you both for the excellent nitpicking. However I am talking of the meaning of the file, not filenames.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: I think we're talking interpreters.  I completely agree that this "question makes no sense."

Comment: -1 While this is all technically correct, it doesn't answer the OP's real question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "run" PHP inside Pytho.

Genshi has `xi:include` but that can include only local files.

It can apparently somehow be tricked into loading data from remote URLs - [Here's](http://groups.google.com/group/genshi/browse_thread/thread/fc080da8f6a81937?pli=1) an answer with some pointers (but no ready-made solution) how to do it.

If you manage to make Genshi fetch a remote file, you can point it to a local PHP URL: `http://localhost/scripts/myscript.php` Be aware however that this will start a remote PHP instance, and probably be slower than a pure filesystem lookup.

I have been in this situation myself when customizing Trac installs. The workaround I always ended up using was having a PHP script run manually or frequently through a cron job, and write into a static file that can be included using `xi:include`.