# PHP Webserver in Python

Tags: php, python

How can I make a PHP 5.3 webserver using Python?

I know how to make a simple HTTP server, but how can I include PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: I basicly want to code a very basic (no vhosts, no htaccess, etc.) Apache alternative, in Python.

Comment: @dorkitude, @vayn A php-server is a piece of software. You can code that piece of software in a language. The language of choice here seems to be python. If someone asks a question about "how to program a browser", your advice would be "open internet explorer" ?

Comment: @Nanne Of course not! "Open FireFox" it would be

Comment: For chrit's sake, it's not that I need a PHP enabled webserver (well, technically it is sort of) but rather that I want to write my own. Basicly, my own version of Apache. @Nanne is right on. I'm a web dev, I have a VPSes, I know how it all works and how to install one when needed. But here, I want to make my own.

Comment: I don't really see what's so strange when a person is asking how to write a piece of software. I agree, the question isn't really specific, and some code and starters would be great, but anyone interested in compiler-building wouldn't get a "there are already compilers" answer? meh.

Comment: @Nanne in fact, he isn't asking how to write a piece of software. He issued 2 short vague sentences in his question, makes his goal extremely obscure.

Comment: True, all true, and I agree that the question isn't up to par at all. But if 'we' want to complain, lets complain about the real issue I suggest. Some of the answers or complaints seem to focus on "you don't want this", and not on "your question should be better"

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps mean writing your own implementation of a PHP module for your own webserver? eg, writing something like mod_php but in python for your own home rolled web server? You would have to have a mighty good reason for pursuing that...check out [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) maybe that will do what you need

Comment: I must say I think down voting this and the other answers on this page is slightly absurd given the vague nature of the original quesiton.

Answer (score -3):

After some clarifications at last it came clear that your question was
"how to connect PHP to HTTP server"

So, actually you were interested in three letters: CGI.

However I still doubt you will get any good from it.

Comment: @Cyril such whim makes no sense